# Custom python Exception with custom message

Tags: python, exception

I want my custom exception be able to print a custom message when it raises. I got this approach (simplifyed):

```
class BooError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(BooError, self).__init__(*args)
        self.message = 'Boo'
```

But the result is not satisfy me:

```
raise BooError('asdcasdcasd')
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hookerror.py", line 8, in <module>
    raise BooError('asdcasdcasd')
__main__.BooError: asdcasdcasd
```

I expected something like:

```
...
__main__.BooError: Boo
```

I know about `message` is deprecated. But I do not know what is the correct way to customize error message?

Comment: In what way does the result not satisfy you? What is the result you want?

Comment: maybe add a `return self.message` statement at the bottom of the `__init__` method? This is probably bad style, but might work :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180185/custom-python-exceptions-with-error-codes-and-error-messages seems to contain the answer you are looking for!

Comment: @PeterLustig Id suggest the answer by Aditya Satyavada that's currently all the way at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set the `args` tuple as well:

```
class BooError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(BooError, self).__init__(*args)
        self.args = ('Boo',)
        self.message = self.args[0]
```

where `self.message` is normally set from the first `args` item. The `message` attribute is otherwise entirely ignored by the `Exception` class.

You'd be far better off passing the argument to `__init__`:

```
class BooError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(BooError, self).__init__('Boo')
```

Comment: Why not pass it as parameter of super __init__?

Comment: Alternatively, he could just do `super(BooError, self).__init__('Boo')`