# Python get an error code from exception

Tags: python, exception, try-except

In python, I have code that handles exceptions and prints error codes and messages.

```
try:
    somecode() #raises NameError
except Exception as e:
    print('Error! Code: {c}, Message, {m}'.format(c = e.code, m = str(e))
```

However, `e.code` is not the proper way to get the error name (NameError), and I cannot find the answer to this. How am I supossed to get the error code?

Comment: Error code (whatever this means) or error name? For the latter, try `type(e).__name__`

Comment: what about `e.message`

Comment: Did you look at the Python documentation for the Exception class?

Comment: use `print( dir(e) )` to see what fields you have in `e`. Every exception may have different fields.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this:

```
try:
    somecode() #raises NameError
except Exception as e:
    print('Error! Code: {c}, Message, {m}'.format(c = type(e).__name__, m = str(e)))
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823936/python-how-do-i-know-what-type-of-exception-occurred) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: This does *not* print the error code, only the name of the exception `NameError` and the exception's message

Comment: Mods: this should not be marked as the correct answer as it does not answer the question.

Comment: See my answer for (what I believe to be) the correct one.

Answer (score 9):

This has worked for me.

```
  except Exception as e:
    errnum = e.args[0]
```

Comment: this dont return a code due to #Dustin Wyatt explanation. Just returns the error message

Answer (score 4):

Python exceptions do not have "codes".

You can create a custom exception that does have a property called `code` and then you can access it and print it as desired.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6180231/23972) answer has an example of adding a `code` property to a custom exception.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is unclear, but from what I understand, you do not want to find the name of the error (`NameError`), but the error code. Here is how to do it. First, run this:

```
try:
    # here, run some version of your code that you know will fail, for instance:
    this_variable_does_not_exist_so_this_code_will_fail
except Exception as e:
    print(dir(e))
```

You can now see what is in `e`. You will get something like this:

```
['__cause__', '__class__', '__context__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__suppress_context__', '__traceback__', 'args', 'with_traceback']
```

This list will include special methods (`__x__` stuff), but will end with things without underscores. You can try them one by one to find what you want, like this:

```
try:
    # here, run some version of your code that you know will fail, for instance:
    this_variable_does_not_exist_so_this_code_will_fail
except Exception as e:
    print(e.args)
    print(e.with_traceback)
```

In the case of this specific error, `print(e.args)` is the closest you'll get to an error code, it will output `("name 'this_variable_does_not_exist_so_this_code_will_fail' is not defined",)`.

In this case, there is only two things to try, but in your case, your error might have more. For example, in my case, a [Tweepy](https://www.tweepy.org/) error, the list was:

```
['__cause__', '__class__', '__context__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__suppress_context__', '__traceback__', '__weakref__', 'api_code', 'args', 'reason', 'response', 'with_traceback']
```

I tried the last five one by one. From `print(e.args)`, I got `([{'code': 187, 'message': 'Status is a duplicate.'}],)`, and from `print(e.api_code)`, I got `187`. So I figured out that either `e.args[0][0]["code"]` or `e.api_code` would give me the error code I'm searching for.

Answer (score -2):

Since it return the object of tuple of tuple of dictionary, we can extract the code as

```
try:
  
  pass

except Exception as e:

  print(e[0][0]['code'] + e[0][0]['message'])
```